# How to mix group expression and cube expression in sparksql group by clause?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cube

I want to use `group by` and `cube` in sparksql, like `select a,b,c,sum(d) from table group by a, cube(b,c)`, but it threw `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`, it seem that I can only use one of them(group expression or cube expression).

This way can success in Postgre or Presto, and wirting the detail how to use in the SparkSql documentation in the following snippet.

```
Mixed/Nested Grouping Analytics

A GROUP BY clause can include multiple group_expressions and multiple CUBE|ROLLUP|GROUPING SETSs. GROUPING SETS can also have nested CUBE|ROLLUP|GROUPING SETS clauses, e.g. GROUPING SETS(ROLLUP(warehouse, location), CUBE(warehouse, location)), GROUPING SETS(warehouse, GROUPING SETS(location, GROUPING SETS(ROLLUP(warehouse, location), CUBE(warehouse, location)))). CUBE|ROLLUP is just a syntax sugar for GROUPING SETS, please refer to the sections above for how to translate CUBE|ROLLUP to GROUPING SETS. group_expression can be treated as a single-group GROUPING SETS under this context. For multiple GROUPING SETS in the GROUP BY clause, we generate a single GROUPING SETS by doing a cross-product of the original GROUPING SETSs. For nested GROUPING SETS in the GROUPING SETS clause, we simply take its grouping sets and strip it. For example, GROUP BY warehouse, GROUPING SETS((product), ()), GROUPING SETS((location, size), (location), (size), ()) and GROUP BY warehouse, ROLLUP(product), CUBE(location, size) is equivalent to GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (warehouse, product, location, size), (warehouse, product, location), (warehouse, product, size), (warehouse, product), (warehouse, location, size), (warehouse, location), (warehouse, size), (warehouse)).

GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(GROUPING SETS(warehouse), GROUPING SETS((warehouse, product))) is equivalent to GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((warehouse), (warehouse, product)).
```

Comment: sparksql version is 3.2.0, document link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a not so perfect idea.

```
select a,b,c,sum(d) from table group by cube(a,b,c) having grouping(a)!=1
```

It will still cube column `a`, but then it will delete it afterwards.